# GPUImage - weird dot appeared after applying filters

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm having a problem with GPUImage filter. I've created a filter chain an apply it to a image. 
Everything went well with my IP5c (7.1). But with my new IP6(8.1), some weird triangle "dot" appeared in the filtered image.

Here's the original: 
[image: original image]

And filtered image (Only happens with my IP6):
[image: filtered image]

Did anyone get the same bugs? Any explanation/solution will be much appreciated. :)

More information: I'm using the newest updated version of GPUImage. The bug only happen when I pick the original image from the Library, fine with images taken from camera (Using AVFoundation).

Comment: A similar issue was reported [here](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1823)

Answer (score 0):

Passing `NO` to `smoothlyScaleOutput` on `[GPUImagePicture  initWithImage:smoothlyScaleOutput:]` seems to [resolve](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1893) (workaround) the issue.